# Counting files browsed using javascript

Tags: javascript

I am having a input type of file  and I want to count the number of files being browsed using javascript .

Html code :

```
<INPUT TYPE="file" id="file" NAME="file" value="file" multiple="multiple"/>
```

Javascript :

```
function formvalidations(){
        var numFiles = document.forms["filesharing"]["file"].length;
        alert(numFiles);
        return false;
    }
```

But am getting undefined.Please help me.

http://jsfiddle.net/vYgC6/

Comment: getting undefined from what? Need to show how you use function and give better explanation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this way:

```
function formvalidations() {
    var numFiles = document.forms["filesharing"]["file"].files.length;
    alert(numFiles);
    return false;
}
```

You need to get it from `.files.length`!

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/praveenscience/vYgC6/1/

Answer (score 0):

You want:

```
function formvalidations() {
    var numFiles = document.forms["filesharing"]["file"].files.length;
    alert(numFiles);
    return false;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vYgC6/2/

You should log the following and take a look in your console to get an idea what `.files` gives you:

```
console.log(document.forms["filesharing"]["file"].files);
```

As Halcyon points out, this is a `FileList` object:

http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/#filelist-section

You might also just reference `input#file` with it's `id` instead of through `document.forms`:

```
document.getElementById('file')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
var files_selected = document.forms["filesharing"]["file"].files;
alert(files_selected.length);
```

`.files` gives you a [`FileList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileList)